# Add user text input to url

Tags: javascript, html, css, append

I'm creating a site and have a text field where you can enter text and it will append itself to the url. Right now I have the system somewhat working however, a page won't show up.

Here is the code I have:

```
<script>
    function changeText2() {
        var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
        var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
        lnk.href = "http://jwallach.prepdev.org/" + userInput;
        window.location = "http://jwallach.prepdev.org/" + userInput;
    }
</script>   

Link <a href="" id=lnk>nothing </a>
<br>
<input type='text' id='userInput' value=' ' />
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Change Link' />
```

However, the page cannot be found because of the %20 in front of the URL. How might I fix this?
[Site](http://jwallach.prepdev.org/)

Answer (score 4):

Either remove the leading space from the input:

```
<input type='text' id='userInput'/>
```

...or trim the content:

```
function changeText2(){
  var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value.trim();
  var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
  lnk.href = "http://jwallach.prepdev.org/" + userInput;
  window.location = "http://jwallach.prepdev.org/" + userInput;
}
```

The latter is a better idea since leading/trailing spaces are a common mistake a user makes when typing/pasting in a field.

If the user isn't knowingly entering in part of a URL, you should also make sure to *URL encode* their input in case their input contains non-URL-safe characters:

```
lnk.href = "http://jwallach.prepdev.org/" + encodeURIComponent(userInput);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just remove the %20 from the input value. :)

So this..

```
<input type='text' id='userInput' value=' ' />
```

becomes this..

```
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change this: `<input type='text' id='userInput' value=' ' />`

to this: `<input type='text' id='userInput'>`

Due to the `value` attribute, a `space` or `%20` was the default value inside the input tag. `%20` is nothing just the ASCII encoding reference value of  `space`. Learn more about ASCII value reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Either start typing the value after hitting backspace a couple of time, or just change `value=" "` to `value=""` or simply remove the `value` attribute and it will solve the issue right away.

The `%20` will pop again if the user hits space by mistake. So what you can do is, trim the input.

Make the following change in the your script tag.

```
<script>
  function changeText2(){
var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value.trim();
var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
lnk.href = "http://jwallach.prepdev.org/" + userInput;
window.location = "http://jwallach.prepdev.org/" + userInput;
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps. :)